# Attempting to get a key where value is equal to in Realtime Database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have the following structure:

```
attendanceOptions: 
  uid: "specificemail@email.com",
  uid: "anotherEmail@email.com",
```

I'm attempting to get the key and value where value is...
In example get where anotherEmail@email.com

Here is my attempt:

security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "organization": {
      "$uid": {
        "attendanceOptions": {
          ".indexOn": ["$uid"]
        },
        "members": {
          ".indexOn": ["mStatus"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error I get is

> Error saving rules - Line 9: Invalid key: $uid. Index must be either .value or declared on a valid path

Obviously I'm doing something wrong.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The way you're trying to define the index makes no sense, but it's hard to say what it *should* actually be. Can you edit your question to show the actual JSON that you're trying to index all the way from the root (text only please, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). --- It'd also be helpful to see the code that is trying to execute a query against that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to define an index on `attendanceOptions` for the value of each child node, you can do that with:

```
"attendanceOptions": {
  ".indexOn": [".value"]
},
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [indexing by value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data#section-indexing-order-by-value).